# Suppress console message from predict of Scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have built Predictive model with Scikit learn. I have deployed this model with Flask, joblib. Whenever I predict for new incoming request with loaded models, its printing message on console about total time taken on cores.

Now, I want to disable this print. How can i suppress the given message while model predicts for new incoming data.

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 117 out of 174 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 121 out of 179 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 122 out of 181 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 123 out of 183 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 125 out of 185 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 127 out of 188 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 128 out of 190 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 129 out of 192 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 132 out of 196 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 133 out of 198 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 135 out of 201 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 137 out of 204 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 138 out of 205 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 140 out of 208 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 143 out of 213 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 148 out of 220 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 149 out of 222 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 153 out of 228 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 155 out of 231 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 159 out of 237 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 165 out of 246 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 168 out of 250 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 169 out of 252 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 171 out of 255 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 173 out of 258 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 177 out of 264 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 181 out of 270 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 183 out of 273 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 185 out of 276 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 187 out of 279 | elapsed:    0.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 335 out of 500 | elapsed:    0.3s remaining:    0.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 500 out of 500 | elapsed:    0.3s finished
```

Comment: Can you indicate which model you're using, there is usually a `verbose` param which you can modify

Comment: I am using model = GaussianNB() , Naive bayes model .

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar complaint while using sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression. In this method, I could find **no** verbose argument in either the .fit() method or the constructor. So the python code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as LR

lr = LR()
y = np.random.rand(100) + 0.01 * np.arange(100)     # noisy line to fit    
x = np.arange(100)
x = np.reshape(y,[100,1])
lr.fit(x,y)
```

I get the annoying output:

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
```

Because the fit() method returns a pointer to itself, and this text represents that object. A simple way to suppress this is by amending the above code to read:

```
a = lr.fit(x,y)
```

Thereby assigning the pointer to some variable and not your screen.

Comment: Instead of using `a` (or any other variable, for that case), I would recommend using `_`, since it is common to [use it for ignoring output values from a function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/underscore-in-python). Therefore, the line would read

`_ = lr.fit(x,y)`

Answer (score 5):

If the unwanted output is produced because `verbose = True` was in the model's constructor, it can be changed as a member variable later:

```
from sklearn.some_category import SomeModel as M

m = M(verbose=True)
m.fit(x, y)  # has output
m.verbose = False
m.predict(x) # no output
```

Comment: Yes, I think the two other answer fail(ed) to actually answer the question: They simply turn off all output, whereas the question explicitly asks how to turn off after instantiation or even after fit. EDIT: I made a slight change to my answer, to make it even clearer...

Comment: Do you know for a fact that all models have a verbose attribute?

Comment: Sorry, I fear not. It's hard to know something like that for a fact, isn't it? Especially, since the sklearn devs could add a new model right now, which may not have it. You could also ask the same question about the `verbose` argument used in the other answers to silence the messages completely... Why are you asking?

Comment: This is the answer for a pre-fitted model

Comment: @Justas Yes, that is the perfect application for it.

Comment: this is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `verbose` parameter to `False`.

> verbose: int, optional : The verbosity level: if non zero, progress
>   messages are printed. Above 50, the output is sent to stdout. The
>   frequency of the messages increases with the verbosity level. If it
>   more than 10, all iterations are reported.

for example using SVM model

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

Comment: Mir, I want to disable this for predict method. I have data in GBs, and there are multiple models so I cant rebuild them. However, if I do it while model building will it disable it ?

Comment: Is there any other option ?